# Clonezilla Server en Ubuntu Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

tengo un problema al montar el clonezilla server en un ubuntu 18.04 en VirtuaBox, una vez hecha la configuración de clonezilla y drbl, al querer montar ordenadores por multicast, me aparece un error

> /home/partimg/nombredelaiso not found

en mi `partimg` esta montado un disco duro de 2TB, con guest additions, con automontar y permanente.

Sería de gran ayuda si me respondierais, gracias de antemano.

Comment: permisos de la carpeta? tal vez necesites agregar los servicios involucrados al group owner del punto de montaje

Comment: Lo intente, pero al intentar darle permisos, no me los coje se queda con los que ya tiene